# How can I get object from another object, only with needed keys?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have one strange question about Destructuring in the JS. How can I get object from another object, only  with needed keys.
For example, to transform this object:

```
let firstObj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4
};
```

To this:

```
let secondObj = {
    a: 1,
    d: 4
};
```

I have array with first type objects. For some reasons I should to use minimal code for this.
My minimum code:

```
arrayObj = [firstObj, firstObj, firstObj, firstObj, firstObj];
let secondArr = arrayObj.map(
  ({a, d}) => ({a, d})
);
```

How can I improve this one?

Comment: `map` is an array's function, not an object's one. `firstObj.map()` doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have any condition to filter keys?

Comment: @sjahan, thanks, updated

Comment: @Dineshundefined, I have list of keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an IIFE for takeing the wanted properties and return a new object.

```js
var first = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 },
    second = (({ a, d }) => ({ a, d }))(first);

console.log(second);
```

With an array of keys for a dynamic approach

```js
var first = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 },
    keys = ['a', 'd']
    second = Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: first[k] })));

console.log(second);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
My bad, I have  array with first type objects and update question

Comment: @inceon, actually i do not understand the question anymore. please add a real example, not just some pseudo code.

Comment: to answer your question, no, you can not make it smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a array with your needed keys and use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on that array to get values from `firstObj`.

**DEMO**

```js
const neededKeys = ['a', 'd'],
      firstObj = {a: 1,b: 2,c: 3,d: 4};

let result = neededKeys.reduce((r, v) => Object.assign(r,{[v]:firstObj[v]}), {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```